# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting if cell value contains value in range

Tags: arrays, list, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I saw an example a few days ago about using SUM but I cannot find it now...
What I want to do:

Sheet 1 Column A holds comma separated lists
  example:

- A1 -> dog, cat, goat
- A2 -> pig, sheep, monkey

Sheet 2 Column A holds individual list items per row
  example:

- A1 -> Pig
- A2 -> Cow
- A3 -> Goat

I want Sheet 1 to highlight cell if it finds a value from range in Sheet2

I have tried text contains Sheet2!A:A
and a couple of custom formulas such as
SEARCH(Sheet2!A:A, Sheet1!A:A) (and FIND)
and even FIND(Sheet1!A1, "pig" OR "cat") <- this works for one value not AND/OR
not sure if I need to use arrayformula because I guess I dont really know what arrayformula is doing to what values.

I suppose I could write a search loop script but I thought I could get this done fairly easy with conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this conditional formatting custom formula:

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(LEN(A1)*REGEXMATCH(A1,"(?i)(^|, )"&INDIRECT("Sheet2!A:A")&"($|, )")))`

applied to range A:A. Note: this will not require matches to be case-sensitive.